Stove socket with unconnected cable plugged in caused breaker to trip
I plugged in an unconnected cable to a stove outlet and it caused the breaker to trip. What could be the problem?

What do you mean by "an unconnected cable"? A cable that is literally connected to nothing? (In which case Ecnerwal is correct) Or a cable connected to your stove but "not plugged in"?

Most likely your oven shorted to ground. Use a voltimeter to test it. Keep that breaker in the "off" position til you know damn sure what's going on.

It was not connected to the stove. We were in process of replacing the stove cable as it has a different socket.

So, with the breaker off, take the cover off your stove receptacle and take a nice clear picture showing the wiring coming into that box. [Edit] your question to add it. All too often there's support for a (safer) NEMA14-50 (4-prongs) but someone slapped a (less safe) NEMA 10-50 (3 prongs, no ground) in there. I don't know which direction you're thinking to swap, but if there's any way that a 4 prong can be properly connecteed, it's definitely the better option. 10-50's have been "only for repair of the same" since the 1996 code cycle. They kill a few people every year...

You probably should hire an electrician.  The breaker did its job, which is save your life.  You should not rely on that strategically.

It was not connected to the stove ... it probably had bare wires at the stove end

Presumably the "unconnected" ends were not properly "isolated" and touched, short-circuiting the outlet. Lower odds, but possible, for things like loose wire in box touching the box and shorting out to happen.
Regardless, this is a suicidally foolish thing to do in any case, with no possible good reason existing to do it. So don't.

Thank you. We were idiots.

Well, you were ignorant. We all start that way. The trick is realizing when you don't know something and finding out before you attempt it... but it is not uncommon for people to not understand that they don't understand. Websearch "Dunning-Kruger Effect."
